# How handle multiple objects with EventEmitter - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, event-handling, eventemitter

Main File

```
var DogModule = require('Dog');
var dogsList = [];

function addNewDog(){
  var newDog = new Dog();
  dogsList.push(newDog);
}

???.on('bark', function(barkSound) {
    console.log(barkSound);
});
```

Dog File

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

function Dog() {

    EventEmitter.call(this);

    this.name = "asda";
    this.chipId = 1234;

    this.emit('bark', "au-au");
}

Dog.prototype = {

   getName: function () {
     return this.name;
   },

   getChipId: function () {
     return this.chipId;
   }
}
```

---

**Question  1** - How can i properly add EventEmitter.prototype to Dog object and save the current prototype and basically just get access to EventEmitter methods?

- Dog.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype);
- Using util module and then util.inherits(Dog, EventEmitter);

The problem here is just how to not overwrite the existing methods...

---

**Question  2** - Handle one object its no problem but for multiple how i can handle them individuality, knowing that they will be stored on that list?

Thank you.

Comment: For inheriting, follow the standard Node docs on extending EventEmitter: https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_inheriting_from_eventemitter

Comment: As i said above the problem is that using util.inherits(Dog, EventEmitter) (as on documentation) overwrite the existing methods of Object prototype.

Comment: You put the ` util.inherits(Dog, EventEmitter)` first and then you add each method individually as in `Dog.prototype.getName = function() {}` so you don't overwrite the previous prototype.  Doing this `Dog.prototype = {...}` overwrites any previous `Dog.prototype`, so don't do that.

Comment: Tbh i knew that, but its kinda painful to reformat the entire prototype when the object have about 100 methods. Thats why i asked hoping a more efficient solution.

Comment: You can merge an object full of methods with the prototype.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent rewriting the prototype, you can use `Object.assign`:

```
util.inherits(Dog, EventEmitter);
Dog.prototype = Object.assign({
  getName: function () {
    return this.name;
  },
  getChipId: function () {
    return this.chipId;
  }
}, Dog.prototype);
```

Comment: Great find, its part of ES6 new features! Btw any idea about the question 2? 
The first was more curiosity :p